OWL conditional if... then
I am working with Protegé and trying to create an OWL file that allows inferring that if “child1” and “child2” have the same “mother1”, then “child1” and “child2” are siblings. That is, in the instances, only the relationships between mothers and children are explicitly given, but not the sibling relationships between children. These non-explicit sibling relationships are what I want to obtain through the reasoner.
I have defined the object property “isSiblingOf” as follows:
<owl:ObjectProperty rdf:about="http://example.org/family#isSiblingOf">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="http://example.org/family#Child"/>
    <rdfs:range>
        <owl:Restriction>
            <owl:onProperty rdf:resource="http://example.org/family#isChildOf"/>
            <owl:someValuesFrom rdf:resource="http://example.org/family#Mother"/>
        </owl:Restriction>
    </rdfs:range>
</owl:ObjectProperty>`

However, it does not generate the inference. The main difficulty I have is defining that the value of the mother must be the same for two children to be siblings.

that's beyond OWL or if possible getting weird with inverse and property chains - you should try to use the easier to read and construct rule language SWRL: isChildOf(?c1, ?m), isChildOf(?c2,?m) -> isSiblingOf(?c1,?c2) - I omitted the "Mother" part, but if you need it, just do isChildOf(?c1, ?m), isChildOf(?c2,?m), Mother(?m) -> isSiblingOf(?c1,?c2)

Thank you very much, @UninformedUser, I'll try with SWRL and I will keep the community informed of my progress.
